# Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 1

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have installed node version 12.6.1 on the windows machine.
I have been trying to create react app on my machine using the following command:-

```
npx create-eact-app my-app
```

the error:-

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "Ahmad\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\2904" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Saood Ahmad\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-01T06_56_47_636Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 1
```

screenshot  [error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH7lz.png)

please guide me through
Thanks

Comment: Issue related here: github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4058

Answer (score 5):

this error occurred because you have a space in your username.
you can solve this problem by installing create-react-app globally:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

then simply run:

```
create-react-app my-app
```

(be carefull you have a typo in your explanation:
npx create-eact-app my-app => npx create-**r**eact-app my-app

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by making sure you install create-react-app in your machine.

Run the following commands, either you install create-react-app globally or not

```
npm install create-react-app
```

or

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```